# AcceptButton directive?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

Code:

```
form1.AcceptButton = accessButton;
```

and I put:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

but it doesnt find it. It says `System.Web.UI.HtmlControl.HtmlForm` doesnt have this definition. Uhm?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms and System.Web.UI.HtmlControl.HtmlForm are two very different things. Windows Forms is for creating desktop-applications and System.Web.UI is for creating ASP.NET-solutions. What do you want to do?

Comment: Web side :) ASP.NET, I'm in a MasterPage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the controls in a panel and set the `DefaultButton` :

```
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="accessButton" runat="server">     
  <asp:TextBox id="myname" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button id="accessButton" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

System.Windows.Forms and System.Web.UI are two completely distinct systems. Windows Forms are for creating desktop-applications and System.Web.UI is for creating ASP.NET-pages. You can't use WinForms in ASP.NET.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.aspx) on ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Page.Form.DefaultButton` instead.